# Batch - For loop - Set two variables in loop to sqlcmd

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, sqlcmd

I have this batch that get the **free space** about the devices that my system has and the name of they (`C:\`, `D:\`, etc).

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK get FreeSpace /format:list 2^>NUL'
) do (sqlcmd -v varSpace="%%I" column="FIELD1" -i C:\cmdutils\test.sql)

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%U in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK get name /format:list 2^>NUL'
) do (sqlcmd -v varSpace="%%U" column="FIELD2" -i C:\cmdutils\test.sql)
```

The **sql file** does an insert:

```
USE [BBDD_SYSTEM]
INSERT INTO SYS_TABLE ($(column)) VALUES ('$(varSpace)')
```

The problem is the **first for loop insert 3 rows** (I have 3 disks) with the **free space** and the **second loop insert 3 rows** more with the **name**, **total 6 rows**

The **correct operation** is 3 rows in total with the space and name.

How can I join the two loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two `wmic` command lines you are using, like this:

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%I in ('
    2^> nul wmic LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size /FORMAT:TABLE
') do (
    if not "%%K"=="" (
        sqlcmd -v varSpace="%%I" column="FIELD1" -v varName="%%J" column="FIELD2" -i C:\cmdutils\test.sql
    )
)
```

There are the 3 fields `FreeSpace`, `Name`, `Size` returned in table format. The first line is skipped by `for /F`, because it is the header. Then only the first 2 fields `FreeSpace` and `Name` are extracted but `Size` is not; this has just been added so that the needed field `Name` is not the last one, because `wmic` produces Unicode output, and `for /F` does proper conversion to ANSI but not for the last field.

The `if not "%%K"==""` query is intended to filter out disks that are not formatted. For such disks, both `FreeSpace` and `Size` are empty, so there is only one token `Name`.

**Caution:**
I am definitely not sure about the `sqlcmd` command line, actually I was just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

With `WMIC`:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('wmic LOGICALDISK get freespace^,name /format:table ^| findstr "[0-9] :"') do (
  echo Do something SQL with Drive : [%%b] Free : [%%a]
)
```

Another way is to use the `DIR` command piped in  `Find "Bytes "`to get the 2 variables :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $c=1
set "$drive=c: d: e:"
for %%a in (%$Drive%) do (
   for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%b in ('2^>nul dir %%a ^|find "bytes "') do (
      echo Do something SQL with Drive : [%%a] Free : [%%b]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (
 'wmic LOGICALDISK get FreeSpace^,name /format:list' 
 ) DO (
 IF /i "%%a"=="Freespace" SET "free=%%b"
 IF /i "%%a"=="Name" (
  SET "name=%%b"
  ECHO sqlcmd -v varSpace="!free:~0,-1!" column="FIELD1" -v varSpace="!name:~0,2!" column="FIELD2" -i C:\cmdutils\test.sql
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This worked for me, but I'm not sure of the `sqlcmd` syntax (the `sqlcmd` is simply `echo`ed)